# PHP Session variables not passing across pages

Tags: php, session, path

Common problem, but I'm stumped.  Session variables are passing across pages on my local (localhost) deployment, but not on my (www) host.  I use a common includes file for each page with this code:

```
$sessionDomain = "/";
@ini_set("session.cookie_path",$sessionDomain);
$sessionName = "ccSID".md5('/store/');
session_name($sessionName);
session_start();
```

I confirmed that the session ID cookie (ccSIDxxxxx...) remains the same across pages in my browser, but session variables don't seem to hold up when changing to a page in a different directory.

EDIT: My session cookie file has legible data from one path directory, but not another.  I noticed that the good directory has a blank php.ini file in it.  When I place a blank php.ini file in the bad directory, the session cookie becomes legible but then regular browser cookies don't save from pages in that directory.  What's the deal with (blank) php.ini files in directories that change the behaviour of the session cookie?

Comment: Did you check whether the cookie is accepted and sent in subsequent requests?

Comment: As long as I request pages from the same directory, the (session) cookies stay set.  Request from a different directory, cookie is gone.

Comment: But you said quite contrary in your question - `I confirmed that the session ID cookie remains the same across pages `. And now you said cookie is gone. Anyway you have to get rid of the all this fun stuff leaving `session_start();` only. I am sure you will get your site working. HTTP interchange log would also help in cookie debugging.

Comment: Sorry, the session_name (browser) cookie remains the same.  But (session) cookies (or session variables) (e.g. $_SESSION['test']) do not.  Why does this work locally and not on my host?

Comment: Nobody can tell you except for HTTP sniffer. Run some while you surf your site and watch what exact cookie does server set

Comment: What should I look for in HTTP sniffer?  I clearly see the browser cookies set as they should, but this won't show me session variables.

Comment: What exactly do you see in the Set-Cookie header?

Comment: Set-Cookie: ccUser=OTI1ODMyYTNkNjc2MGJhYjdlYWIyZTU3MzM0MjE2ZTg%3D; expires=Tue, 23-Mar-2010 18:34:39 GMT; path=/
What's this got to do with session variables?

Comment: If I'm not blind, the "ccUser" string is slightly different from the complex session name you devised above. And it is different from the **default** PHPSESSID too. Well well. Looks like it is clear whom to blame.

Comment: Your keen observation is accurate (although sarcasm un-called for), ccUser is not ccSIDxxx.  Hope this makes you feel better:
Set-Cookie: ccSID285e73f64c04744fc5f33ff68f529742=bf763d13b2facc331ac13662eb3a8124; path=/

Now, wise one, tell me the answer to the problem!

Comment: Looks like you came here to argue, not to solve your problem. See ya

Comment: It's no wonder you have 49 positive votes and 79 negative votes!  I'll wait for someone else with a technical response to my technical question.

Comment: Your "technical question" belongs to debugging, if you ever happen to hear this word. And you fail with it. Even under my guide, you're doing it as if it's my problem, not yours.

Comment: Why do you have error suppression opperator in front of ini_set? You could be blocking an error that you want to see. Remove it. Always handle known errors and don't suppress all potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

"/" looks like a path, not domain.
Why don't you just leave session settings alone, with default values?
if session cookie goes all right, you have to check files within session.save_path

Answer (score 1):

I have a sneaking feeling that you're saving cookies in more than one place. Since you're naming them yourself the name might be the same, but it would in effect be a completely different session.

Look on your server at the actual session files. Are they all where they're supposed to be? Are there a bunch showing up where they don't belong?

If this is the case it you're path is probably being set relative rather than absolute even though it doesn't look like it from what you've shown here.

Also, perhaps you should take the shutup operator (@) off of your ini_set() so you can see if it is complaining about anything?

Comment: I have since placed my session array by using session.save_path and am now observing that file.  Looks fine when saving variables from one page, but weird when saving from another (as if the cookie is encoded).  Again, works fine this way on my local.

Comment: Session data is being saved where I expect and when I expect, but when testing with a simple variable ($_SESSION['test'] = 'test';), it is unintelligible from one page, but clear from another.  It is definitely saving to the same session name and place, but garbled from on page and not from another.

Comment: I get (test|s:4:"test";) with the problem page on my local server (is working fine), but I get (iFcXRQdc4KoZBgg2AMi4hKTzR380YphO8xCK4fK6IDPIRrbk7Nnnaq06FlbbH0YmBGzMbMy85TVGXPyDdDI5KMtq08PQMuK6ypGKKyYDowA.) when trying same on my host server.

Comment: Just tested again with simple file to set a session variable.  Only moved the file from one path directory to another and get the garbled cookie.

Comment: Seems to work if I place an empty php.ini file in the directory with the problem, but that causes a problem with setting cookies?!?!

Comment: That's strange. Unfortunately I don't know what could be causing that. Perhaps you should edit your question and mention that is happening in case someone else would know?